# If Else statement Powershell CSV with Output CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am fairly new in powershell scripting and need help on the following output in a csv format. I am trying to select a column e.g. ACCOUNT.UPLOAD and make and if/else statement to output it in another csv file. May someone help please.

[image: Sample1]

Output csv should look like below:

[image: Sample2]

```
$results = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\customer.csv' |
Select-Object "ACCOUNT.UPLOAD"

ForEach ($row in $results) 
{
    If ($row.Type0 -ne 'CP000101', 'CP000102')
    { 
        $row."ACCOUNT.UPLOAD" = "$($row.ACCOUNT.UPLOAD)"
        Write-Host $row."ACCOUNT.UPLOAD"
    }
}   
$results | Export-Csv C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Thank you

Comment: (a) `$results` contains objects with just _one_ property, namely the `ACCOUNT.UPLOAD` property you've extracted with `Select-Object`. (b) Thus, the `$row` objects in your loop have no `Type0` property (which isn't even in your CSV input). (c) the RHS of `-ne` doesn't support _arrays_ - use operator `-in` instead. (d) `$row."ACCOUNT.UPLOAD" = "$($row.ACCOUNT.UPLOAD)"` is a no-op, given that everything read from a CSV file is a string to begin with - what are you trying to do? Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you what you need. Added comments to explain what I have done.

```
$results = Import-Csv "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\customer.csv" | Select-Object "ACCOUNT.UPLOAD"
# Created array to be able to add individual results from foreach
$TheCSV = @()

ForEach ($row in $results) {
    # You can use a -ne in the right hand side, if done like this.
    If (($row.'ACCOUNT.UPLOAD' -ne 'CP000101') -and $row.'ACCOUNT.UPLOAD' -ne 'CP000102') {
        # Adds the ROW column to the entry and finds the index that it was in from $results.
        # Did a +2 as it does not include the header and it starts at value 0. So to match it up with the actual excel row numbers, add 2.
        $row | Add-Member -Name 'ROW' -type NoteProperty -Value "$([array]::IndexOf($results.'ACCOUNT.UPLOAD',$row.'ACCOUNT.UPLOAD')+2)"
        $TheCSV += $row
    }
}
$TheCSV | Export-Csv "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow Sir! You made my day! Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

Do it PowerShell way:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    $InputFile = 'D:\\Temp\\Data.csv',
    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    $OutputFile = 'D:\\Temp\\Output.csv'
)

Import-Csv $InputFile |
    Select-Object "ACCOUNT.UPLOAD" |
    %{
        $lineno++
        if ($_.'ACCOUNT.UPLOAD' -notin @('CP000101', 'CP000102')) {
            $_ | Add-Member -Name 'ROW' -type NoteProperty -Value $lineno
            $_ # Output to pipeline
        }
    } -Begin { $lineno = 1 } |
    Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Using:

```
.\Script.ps1

.\Script.ps1 inputfilename.csv outputfilefname.csv
```